Connection between Markov Chains and Exponential Distribution
In Continuous Time Markov Chains (CTMC), I often hear that the time spent in each state is exponentially distributed and thus obeys the memoryless property. But something I have always wondered: From a theory perspective, (1st option) did we purposefully develop CTMCs and have this assumption of the exponential distribution from the start - (2nd option) or did we develop CTMCs and later realize that for a CTMC to work, the exponential distribution is required?
As a proof of concept, I tried to show some analysis of CTMCs, and it seems to me that the exponential distribution property is a natural consequence (i.e. 2nd option).
In a continuous-time Markov chain:
Let $X(t)$ be the state at time $t$.
Define the transition rate from state $i$ to state $j$ as:
$$ q_{ij} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{P(X(t+h) = j | X(t) = i)}{h}, \quad i \neq j $$
The total rate of leaving state $i$ is:
$$ q_i = \sum_{j \neq i} q_{ij} $$
Now, let's consider the probability that no transition occurs in the interval $(0, t)$, given that we start in state $i$. We'll call this probability $P_i(t)$.
For a small time interval $h$:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P_i(t) \cdot (1 - q_i h + o(h)) $$
Rearranging:
$$ \frac{P_i(t+h) - P_i(t)}{h} = -q_i P_i(t) + \frac{o(h)}{h} $$
Taking the limit as $h \to 0$:
$$ \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} = -q_i P_i(t) $$
This is a differential equation with the solution:
$$ P_i(t) = e^{-q_i t} $$
Now, the probability density function $f(t)$ for the time until the next transition is:
$$ f(t) = q_i e^{-q_i t} $$
This is the probability density function of an exponential distribution with rate parameter $q_i$, which is the total transition rate out of the current state.
The cumulative distribution function $F(t)$ is:
$$ F(t) = 1 - e^{-q_i t} $$
Therefore, in CTMCs, the exponential distribution is not needed a priori and is a natural result.
Is my conclusion correct?

Note 1: Solution of the differential equation
$$ \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} = -q_i P_i(t) $$
to:
$$ P_i(t) = e^{-q_i t} $$
We start:
$$ \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} = -q_i P_i(t) $$
$$ \frac{dP_i(t)}{P_i(t)} = -q_i dt $$
$$ \int \frac{dP_i(t)}{P_i(t)} = \int -q_i dt $$
$$ \ln|P_i(t)| = -q_i t + C $$
$$ P_i(t) = e^{-q_i t + C} $$
$$ P_i(t) = e^C \cdot e^{-q_i t} $$
$$ P_i(t) = A e^{-q_i t} $$
Here, $A = e^C$ is a constant. To determine $A$, we use the initial condition that $P_i(0) = 1$ (probability of no transition at time 0 is 1):
$$ P_i(0) = A e^{-q_i \cdot 0} = A = 1 $$
Therefore, the final solution is:
$$ P_i(t) = e^{-q_i t} $$
Now, to get from $P_i(t)$ to $f(t)$:
$$ P_i(t) = e^{-q_i t} $$
This is the probability that no transition has occurred by time $t$. The probability density function $f(t)$ is the derivative of the complement of this probability:
$$ f(t) = \frac{d}{dt} (1 - P_i(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} (1 - e^{-q_i t}) $$
$$ f(t) = q_i e^{-q_i t} $$
This is the probability density function of an exponential distribution with rate parameter $q_i$.

Note 2: Justification for the probability that no transition occurs in the interval $(0, t)$, given that we start in state $i$:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P_i(t) \cdot (1 - q_i h + o(h)) $$
For no transition to occur in the interval $(0, t+h)$:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P(\text{no transition in } (0,t) \text{ AND no transition in } (t,t+h)) $$
We can write this as the product of two probabilities:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P(\text{no transition in } (0,t)) \cdot P(\text{no transition in } (t,t+h) \mid \text{no transition in } (0,t)) $$
The first probability is exactly our definition of $P_i(t)$. For the second probability, we need to consider what happens in the small interval $(t,t+h)$:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P_i(t) \cdot P(\text{no transition in } (t,t+h) \mid X(t) = i) $$
Now, for the probability of no transition in $(t,t+h)$, we can use the complement of the probability that a transition does occur:
$$ P(\text{no transition in } (t,t+h) \mid X(t) = i) = 1 - P(\text{transition occurs in } (t,t+h) \mid X(t) = i) $$
The probability of a transition occurring in a small interval $h$ is approximately $q_i h$ for small $h$, based on the definition of $q_i$. However, we need to account for higher-order terms, which we denote as $o(h)$:
$$ P(\text{no transition in } (t,t+h) \mid X(t) = i) = 1 - (q_i h + o(h)) $$
Substituting this back:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P_i(t) \cdot (1 - (q_i h + o(h))) $$
Distributing the terms:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P_i(t) \cdot (1 - q_i h - o(h)) $$
This gives us the final formula:
$$ P_i(t+h) = P_i(t) \cdot (1 - q_i h + o(h)) $$
